# Initializing UserManager<TUser> in class library project

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, asp.net-core-identity, usermanager

I have an ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC application and a .NET 5.0 class library called `Application.Data`. Due to separation of concerns, I decided that the `DbContext` and migrations should be contained within the data library. The DDL migrations work perfectly, but I'm having issues seeding `AspNetCore.Identity` users from within the data library.

Simply put, I want to access a `UserManager<MyUser>` instance in order to invoke the `CreateAsync`/`AddToRoleAsync` methods, but the `UserManager` constructor takes eight parameters that then also need to be instantiated. My understanding is that I could inject the user manager using the `AddIdentity` method to the service collection of my MVC project, but since my `DbContext` is contained within `Application.Data`, I wouldn't be able to run migration commands from within the MVC project.

What is the best course of action here?

Comment: You can define a data seeding class/method in your `Application.Data` library and call it from the MVC web project passing the `UserManager`.